# Signaling, firewall and NAT traversal simplewebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm a noob, and I'm starting to learn about webRTC, recently I found a web page called simplewebrtc, I read about the demo, but I don't understand how they manage the firewalls and NAT traversal in a network, I know that webRTC uses STUN Servers but I can't find them in the source code of the demo from simplewebRTC, can anybody explain me that please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently SimpleWebRTC uses the public google STUN server as default, check this [line](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/bdb03caf7f6daf3503d671c7d877648cfc891dde/webrtc.js#L16).

About the NAT/firewall traversal: as you already pointed out this is done using a STUN (or TURN) server. The STUN protocol simply allows clients that are trying to establish a connection to discover each others public IPs, with which they can establish direct connections. If some client is behind a [symmetric NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Symmetric_NAT) then a TURN server that acts as a relay will be necessary.

You can find a more detailed explanation about STUN/TURN [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501288/what-is-stun-and-does-it-need-a-port-forwarded-server#answer-13539963).